# Converting from time domain to phasor domain?

Tags: voltage, ac, signal, phasor

If I have a voltage source of a circuit

\$V_s(t) = 8\cos(24\pi*10^9t-60^{\circ})\$ (V)

and I want to convert it to the phasor domain would it be this?

\$8e^{-j60^{\circ}}\$?

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Comment: Take a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440689/phasors-and-fourier-transform

Comment: The angle is normally expressed in radians. Certain operations, such as Taylor series expansion, and frequency response calculation, need the angle in radians.

Answer (score 2):

The phase 60 degrees should rather be represented in radians as \$\frac{\pi}{3}\$ radians, to be dimensionally consistent with \$\omega t\$.

So in phasor form the voltage will be simply:
$$V=8e^{-j\pi/3}$$